# Why is my vs2012 forcing extra parentheses

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, code-editor

First, thank you for taking pity on me and reading this issue.  I CANNOT for the life of me figure out what extension I might have installed that is causing this issue, but it is EXTREMELY cumbersome.

Whenever I begin to type code (VB I think it also occurs in C#), for example "For Each" once I hit the F it forces a set of parentheses. Which would look like F(), but because I keep typing it looks like F(or).  This only occurs when coding inside code blocks like a function or a sub, but when I'm creating the function it does not occur.   I've disabled any and all power tools and the like, or at least I'm 90% sure I've done this for all of them, and yet it still occurs.

I'm usually pretty proficient at digging about the net and finding the answer, but for this one I'm at a loss.   There is just too many keywords involved, so all I see is non-related topics, or how to make the parentheses occur, not get rid of them.

If anyone can provide some steps to resolve this, I'm happy and eager to try them.  It's just such a hassle to live with for right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer to the cause is the [Codealike](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd5e9ff-d183-46e0-9934-c8832924abb7) VS Extension.  I logged a bug with them and hopefully they'll fix it soon

Answer (score 0):

If you think it is a Visual Studio extension, then start by disabling all of them and adding them back one at a time.

[image]

You can also run VS with the command line switched to disable features.

[Devenv switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll go disable everything again and test, but like I said above, I tried this before and had the same results.  What I fear is that there was some extension or power tool that was installed that is causing this thing, that is the type of extension that can only be uninstalled via add remove programs.  I've attempted /resetpkgs with no luck and really really don't want to have to start uninstalling items to attempt to debug this.   I was hoping someone else out there knows exactly the boat I'm in, as well as how to get back outta it.  I appreciate the input though

Comment: You might want to check to see if you have any custom code snippits installed also.

Comment: Well, After I used the Deven/CleanMode and saw the issue didn't occur, I again went through and disabled them all, then enabled them again 3x at a time.   I was blown away to learn that the cause of the issue was The CodeALike extension.   I never would have guessed it because that just tracks stats of how long you dev and in which env    [link](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4cd5e9ff-d183-46e0-9934-c8832924abb7)   I logged a bug with them, and hopefully they'll fix that soon, I've been a big advocate for their app for a while now, this it quite upsetting indeed.